# JavaScript operation array object merge

Tags: javascript

**I have two arrays, and now I want to merge the two arrays.**

**The first array：**

```
var data = [
    { name: 'aa', value: 1 },
    { name: 'bb', value: 2 },
    { name: 'cc', value: 3 }
];
```

**Two arrays:**

```
var data2 = [
    { name: 'aa' },
    { name: 'bb' },
    { name: 'cc' },
    { name: 'dd' },
    { name: 'ee' }
];
```

**I want to merge them into this:**

```js
var data3 = [
  {name: 'aa', value: 1},
  {name: 'bb', value: 2},
  {name: 'cc', value: 3},
  {name: 'dd', value: 0},
  {name: 'ee', value: 0}
];

console.log(data3)
```

**At present, my experience is not enough. Please help me solve this problem.**

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2):

You can try following based on following assumptions

1. `data2` is a collection of `names` and expecting its length to be always more than length of `data`
2. Order of objects can be different

```js
var data = [
    { name: 'aa', value: 1 },
    { name: 'bb', value: 2 },
    { name: 'cc', value: 3 }
];

var data2 = [
    { name: 'aa' },
    { name: 'bb' },
    { name: 'cc' },
    { name: 'dd' },
    { name: 'ee' }
];

// Iterate over the names array
var data3 = data2.map(({name}) => {
  // get the matched object in data corresponding to the name
  var match = data.find((obj) => obj.name === name);
  // if found, return value else default value to 0
  return match ? match : {name, value : 0};
});

console.log(data3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input arrays are indeed in order like that, then a simple `.map` would suffice:

```js
var data = [
    { name: 'aa', value: 1 },
    { name: 'bb', value: 2 },
    { name: 'cc', value: 3 }
];

var data2 = [
    { name: 'aa' },
    { name: 'bb' },
    { name: 'cc' },
    { name: 'dd' },
    { name: 'ee' }
];
const output = data2.map(({ name }, i) => ({ name, value: data[i] ? data[i].value : 0 }));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object lookup for each `name` using `array#reduce`. Extract all the values using the `Object.values()` from the object lookup.

```js
const data1 = [ { name: 'aa', value: 1 }, { name: 'bb', value: 2 }, { name: 'cc', value: 3 } ],
      data2 = [ { name: 'aa' }, { name: 'bb' }, { name: 'cc' }, { name: 'dd' }, { name: 'ee' } ],
      result = Object.values([data1, data2].reduce((r,a) => {
        a.forEach(({name, value = 0}) => {
          r[name] = name in r ? r[name] : {name, value};
        });
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

You can `array#concat` both the arrays and using `array#reduce` create an object lookup and then get all the values using the `Object.values()`.

```js
const data1 = [ { name: 'aa', value: 1 }, { name: 'bb', value: 2 }, { name: 'cc', value: 3 } ],
      data2 = [ { name: 'aa' }, { name: 'bb' }, { name: 'cc' }, { name: 'dd' }, { name: 'ee' } ],
      result = Object.values(data1.concat(data2).reduce((r,{name, value=0}) => {
        r[name] = name in r ? r[name] : {name, value};
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    { name: 'aa', value: 1 },
    { name: 'bb', value: 2 },
    { name: 'cc', value: 3 }
];
var data2 = [
    { name: 'aa' },
    { name: 'bb' },
    { name: 'cc' },
    { name: 'dd' },
    { name: 'ee' }
];

let output = new Array(data2.length).fill(data2.length).map(v => new Object());
// Logic
 data.forEach((val2)=> {
     data2.forEach((val, i)=> {         
         if (val.name == val2.name){
             output[i]["name"] = val.name
             output[i]["value"] = val2.value
            } else{
                output[i]["name"] = val.name
          }         
     })
    })

    output.map((val,i) => {
        if  (!val.hasOwnProperty("value")){
            console.log(val)
            val["value"] = 0
        }
    })


    console.log("------Your Expected Format", output)
```